# How to solve for n in a summation?

Tags: calculus, probability

I will give you the first part of the answer but I need help solving for $n$ without guessing and checking.

Don't worry about the question, I just need help with the part I am stuck on:

> How many people have to be in a room in order that the probability that at least two of them celebrate their birthday in the same month is at least $\frac12$?
>
> Assume that all possible monthly outcomes are equally likely.

I go up to here but don't know how to solve for $n$ without guessing and checking for the answer.

I know the answer is $5$ but how do I solve it?

$1-((12\times11\times10\times\ldots\times(12-n+1))/(12^n))\geq\frac12$

Comment: Welcome to math.SE. If your answer is just about solving the inequality, please go directly to the point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question, as I understand it, is what is an efficient way to find
the least $n$ such that

$$1- \frac{12\times11\times10\times\cdots\times(12-n+1)}{12^n}\geq\frac12.$$

First, let's get the big ugly fraction all by itself on one side of the formula.
If $1 - x \geq \frac12$ then (adding $x$ to both sides) $1 \geq \frac12 + x$ 
and (subtracting $\frac12$ from both sides) $\frac12 \geq x$.
So we can rewrite the original inequality as

$$\frac{12\times11\times10\times\cdots\times(12-n+1)}{12^n} \leq \frac12.$$

Writing out $12^n$ in the form of a sequence of multiplications, 
$12 \times 12 \times 12 \times \cdots \times 12$, we find that
the original inequality is equivalent to

$$\frac{12\times11\times10\times\cdots\times(12-n+1)}
{\underbrace{12 \times 12 \times 12 \times \cdots \times 12}_\text{$n$ factors}}\leq \frac12.$$
Without changing the value of the left-hand side, we can change the 
sequence of operations (multiplication and division) as follows:

$$\frac{12}{12} \times \frac{11}{12} \times \frac{10}{12} \times \cdots
   \times\frac{12-n+1}{12} \leq \frac12.$$

So a straightforward solution method is to start by
setting $p_1 = \frac{12}{12}$. 
Multiply $p_1$ by $\frac{11}{12}$ and call the result $p_2$.
Multiply $p_2$ by $\frac{10}{12}$ and call the result $p_3$.
Continue with this pattern (decreasing the numerator by $1$ each time)
until the result is less than or equal to $\frac12$.
Suppose that occurs after $k$ steps, that is, $p_k \leq \frac12$.
Then $n = k$.

A slightly different way to get the same result, but without having
to divide by $12$ so many times, is to recognize that
$\dfrac{12-k}{12} = 1 - \dfrac{k}{12}.$
So do the multiplications as follows:

\begin{align}
m_1 &= 1                         & p_1 &= 1 \\
m_2 &= m_1 - \frac{1}{12} \qquad & p_2 &= m_2 \times p_1 \\
m_3 &= m_2 - \frac{1}{12} \qquad & p_3 &= m_3 \times p_2 \\
    & \qquad\vdots                     &     & \qquad\vdots
\end{align}

As before, stop when $p_k \leq \frac12$, and set $n = k$.

---

This problem is a version of the "birthday problem",
which in general assumes you have $n$ people, each of whom has an
equally likely probability of being born on any of $M$ time periods.
It is assumed each person's probability distribution is independent
of all the others.
The time period in your case is months, so $M=12$,
but in the usual formulation the time period is days of the year, with $M=365$.

So the problem becomes to find the least $n$ such that

$$p_n =
 1 \times \left(1 - \frac{1}{M}\right) \times \left(1 - \frac{2}{M}\right)
 \times \left(1 - \frac{3}{M}\right) \times \cdots
  \times \left(1 - \frac{n - 1}{M}\right)  \leq \frac12.$$

As long as $k$ is much smaller than $M$, we can make the approximation

$$ 1 - \frac{k}{M} \approx e^{-k/M},$$

so

$$p_n \approx 1 \times e^{-1/M} \times e^{-2/M} \times e^{-3/M}
   \times \cdots \times e^{-(n-1)/M} = e^{-n(n-1)/(2M)}. $$

(For more about this approximation, see http://www.math.cornell.edu/~mec/2008-2009/TianyiZheng/Birthday.html,
for example.) Then

\begin{align}
\ln(p_n) & \approx -\frac{n(n-1)}{2M} \\
-2M \ln(p_n) & \approx n(n-1) = \left(n - \frac12\right)^2 - \frac14  \\
\left(n - \frac12\right)^2 & \approx \frac14 - 2M \ln(p_n) \\
n & \approx \frac12 + \sqrt{\frac14 - 2M \ln(p_n)}
\end{align}

If we set $M = 12$ and $p_n = \frac12$ then
by this formula, $n \approx 4.609$, so for $p_n < \frac12$ we can 
guess that $n > 4.609$ and therefore $n = 5$,
which turns out to be the right answer.

Comment: i understand the part where you change the order of operations but what happens to the ^n from the 12 in the denominator? why does that disappear?

Comment: @idknuttin $12^n$ is just $n$ factors of $12$ multiplied together. None of those factors disappeared. For example, $12^4 = 12\times12\times12\times12$, right? Despite the fact that there's no $4$ on the right hand side? I've inserted an intermediate step in the work that I hope makes it clearer what happened with the $n$.

Comment: I understand how to do it now, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Assume the year has $m$ months. We want to find minimal $n$ such that 
$$ \frac{m!}{(m-n)!\cdot m^n}\le\frac12$$
The factorial function is very unhandy if one wants to solve an expression like this. For small $m$, the probably easiest ways is indeed trying $n=1,2,\ldots $ in sequence until one gets lucky.

---

For muach *larger* values of $m$ one could emply a nice approximation for the factorial that makes it much easier to handle: $m!\approx m^me^{-m}\sqrt{ 2\pi m}$ (and, yes, that expression *is* nicer to handle). With this, we want to solve
$$ \frac{m^me^{-m}\sqrt{2\pi m}}{(m-n)^{m-n}e^{-(m-n)}\sqrt{2\pi (m-n)}\,m^n}\approx \frac 12$$
The left side simplifies to
$$ \frac{1}{\left(1-\frac nm\right)^{m-n+\frac12}e^n}$$
We know that for $m\gg n$, $\left(1-\frac nm\right)^m\approx e^{-n}$ so that we want to solve
$$ \left(1-\frac nm\right)^{n-\frac12}\approx \frac12$$
By ignoring all higher terms in an expansion of the left hand side this becomes
$$ 1-(n-\tfrac12)\cdot \frac nm\approx \frac12$$
and ultimately the approximate solution $n\approx \sqrt{\frac m2}$.
However, this result is quite far off (we just made too many approximations and simplifications above) as it suggests $n\approx 2.4$ instead of $n=5$ when $m=12$; it als suggests $n\approx 13.5$ instead of $n=23$ when $m=365$. (The main problem is that $m\not\gg n$ so that $\left(1-\frac nm\right)^m\not\approx e^{-n}$)